# ProgressBar does not show when I call View.GONE after View.VISIBLE (but only on older phones)

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my xml file for the MainActivity I defined a circular ProgressBar which I want to show whenever my app is doing some loading.

```
private void refresh() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //show progress bar and blur background
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mainActivityScreen.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            /*do something */
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //hide progress bar and unblur background
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainActivityScreen.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

When I run this code on my Nexus 6P, it does exactly what it should. I click the refresh button, a progressBar appears (which was initially invisible), the app does some network operations and when it finishes the progressBar disappears again. Now when I run the same code on an older phone, the progressBar does not show up. At first I thought maybe the phone cannot load the progressBar but that's not the problem, since when I leave out the line

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it shows up (but obviously does not disappear again). It's also not a problem of it not showing long enough to notice, since the network operations take about 2 seconds to complete.

Can someone please tell me why this only works on my newer phone and not an older one? I'm going crazy over this.

Thanks in advance for anyone helping.

EDIT: xml:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: what is the API level of the older phone?

Comment: @AnjalSaneen 23

Answer (score 1):

I see your error;

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPreExecute();  
            //hide progress bar and unblur background
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainActivityScreen.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
```

After your onPostExecute finish you are calling to super.onPreExecute() again.

Remove that line:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //hide progress bar and unblur background
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainActivityScreen.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
```

Comment: That is indeed an error, thank you. But unfortunately it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: are you sure you are not calling progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); in another part of your code?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that. Also if I did, it wouldn't work on my newer phone either.

Comment: could you put the logcat of your older phone?

Comment: could you put your XML file ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a Handler instead of an AsyncTask. Somehow that works on all phones. Thanks for your help anyway!